# Unable to set position of Angular Material 2 dialog using MdDialogConfig

Tags: angular, angular-material, mddialog

Any idea how to set the position of an MdDialog?

```
  openDialog() {
let config = new MdDialogConfig();
config.height = '15px';
config.position.left = '5px';
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BasicAlertDialog, config);
dialogRef.componentInstance.title = this.dialogTitle ;
dialogRef.componentInstance.text = this.dialogText ;
dialogRef.componentInstance.yes = this.dialogYes ;
dialogRef.componentInstance.no = this.dialogNo ;
```

I can set the height, but setting the position results in the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined
    at AppComponent.webpackJsonp.267.AppComponent.openDialog (app.component.ts:385)". Line 385 is where I try to set the left position to 5px.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Material. Dialog box not showing in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414964/angular-2-material-dialog-box-not-showing-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 0):

> you can set like that. does this help!

```
    openDialog() {
       let config = new MdDialogConfig();

       config.height = '15px';
       config.position = {
                left: '5px'
            };
       let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BasicAlertDialog, config);
       dialogRef.componentInstance.title = this.dialogTitle ;
       dialogRef.componentInstance.text = this.dialogText ;
       dialogRef.componentInstance.yes = this.dialogYes ;
       dialogRef.componentInstance.no = this.dialogNo ;
   }
```

Comment: Yes. That works. Thanks! (I swear I tried that earlier. Oh well.)

Answer (score 0):

From my working PoC:

```
  const dialogConfig = new MdDialogConfig();
  dialogConfig.position = { left: '20px' };
  dialog.open(PocModalComponent, dialogConfig);
```